# Why don't questions shown in the review section show votes/answers/views like the rest of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review

Why don't the questions under the tabs for "first answers", "low quality posts", and "late answers" show votes/answers/views like the rest of the questions on Stack Overflow, and only the total number of votes?

Also, why do the questions under the "first questions" tab look like the questions on the rest of the site, but different from the other three tabs that it sits next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about you, but I'd never expect to find a **question** under the tabs for "first **answers**" and "late **answers**" myself. That wouldn't make much sense. Answers don't have all these counts. Most of the "low quality posts" tab is filled with answers, since those tend to be the low quality ones, but occasionally you will run across a question in there. When you do, it will show the normal votes, answers, and views box for the question.

Short answer: they're answers, not questions. All they have is a score. The box to the left is specific to that post. How many upvotes the post has and whether it is the accepted answer. It has nothing to do with the question it belongs too.

Comment: Well, it has *some* to do with the question they belong to.  We expect answers to *answer the question asked.*

Comment: @Robert: I was talking specifically about the box with the number in it, though.