# Late answers in the /review queue (#3) - show all answers

Tags: feature-request, review, late-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing Whole Threads in Answer-Review Section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148739/showing-whole-threads-in-answer-review-section)

Could we please show all the answers for a question when reviewing a late answer?

This can be helpful in a few ways:

- I can quickly see whether the late answer is simply copying or paraphrasing an existing answer
- I can tell whether [up voting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/788425) will have a negative effect in relation to other equally good or better answers already given (i.e. the late answer gets a boost simply because it was late - I can't do this in good conscience)
- I can tell that further action needs to be taken on the reviewed answer even though it appears legit ([answer that was reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/788379), [almost duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621681/109702) from same person under same question)

Basically, for those who like to do their reviews properly it is going to mean we have all the info available to make a good decision on the answer. Note that these were just a couple of examples I picked up in the space of a few minutes.