# 'About' pages should be about the specific Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, tour

I've just noticed that some about pages ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about), [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about) and [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/about)) do not show what the specific Stack Exchange site is about. They explain what Stack Exchange  is, but not what *TeX - LaTeX* is.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

I remember that there was once something like:

> Stack Overflow is for questions about XYZ. If you have questions about A you could go to B.stackexchange.com

or

> Stack Overflow is for questions about XYZ. It is not about A.

When did this change? Why did it change? How are new users supposed to know which questions they should ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), which on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and which on *[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)* (to name just a few)? Is there any chance to get this clarification of scope back (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164779/158075))?

Is it eventually still there and I simply didn't see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About pages still display the text which tells you about what that site is about and this text is different on each site. For example, here is content from a few Stack Exchange sites:

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site **for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers**.
>
> **Programmers** Stack Exchange is a question and answer site **for
>   professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about
>   software development**.
>
> **Super User** is a question and answer site **for computer enthusiasts and
>   power users**.
>
> **Server Fault** is a question and answer site **for professional system and
>   network administrators**.
>
> **Skeptics** is a question and answer site **for applying scientific
>   skepticism**.
>
> **TeX - LaTeX** is a question and answer site **for users of TeX, LaTeX,
>   ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, people who love to create
>   well-structured and beautifully typeset documents**.

Details about what is on-topic and what is counted as off-topic are shown in the Help Center (which is linked from both the About pages and from the top nav bar).

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was look for [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: But one question still remains: Should this pages content (or at least part of it / a link to it) probably be in the "about" page?

Comment: It is linked. On about pages, you'll find this: **Looking for more in-depth information on the site? Visit the Help Center**