# Tour page inconsistency

Tags: feature-request, meta, tour

The [Meta tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) is contradictory.

At the top of the page, per the usual Stack Exchange site, it states very clearly:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's **not** a **discussion** forum. There's no chit-chat.

Then under "Be part of the community that decides how the sites work":

> While we discourage opinions on our main sites, questions here are likely to generate **discussion** and involve opinions. **That's okay!**

Further on, this contradictory view is reinforced:

> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, meta invites the community to **discuss**, debate, and propose changes

(In all cases, emphasis is mine.)

While the "tour" page is understandably templated to be consistent with other Stack Exchange sites, it is clear each has their own in order to allow for underscoring the central thrust of that site. It seems this should be true here, too. Something more like:

> Stack Exchange is all about getting answers, and this meta site is about making the process of doing that. It is a discussion forum for improving <Sister site>.
>
> Just questions...
>
> ... and answers...
>
> ... and discussion of those answers.

(Or, you know, language that is perhaps tuned slightly better to the specific requirement meta has: to dogfood itself, improve the site, support discussion but not so much discussion that it gets in the way of clarifying the way things are and/or should be.)

Comment: My take is that Q&As in Meta work the same way as in SE ie. Specific questions and specific answers. But if a [discussion] tag is added, then and only then it's a permitted discussion. Even that discussion has to follow certain rules. So it's still not a discussion forum like most others.

Comment: I agree it's not a bog standard discussion forum, but there is still a contradiction in how it's presented. The difference is subtle and the current explanation isn't clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should we put on our Tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164778/what-should-we-put-on-our-tour-page)