# "Dummy" Suggested Edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why no honeypot suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits)

Stemming off of my previous questions regarding the "Suggested Edits" review queue:

Why don't we have dummy tests in "Suggested Edits" like we do in "First Posts" and "Late Answers"?