# Bot that randomly edits questions?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

From reviewing suggested edits on Stack Overflow, I notice that there are some edits proposed that are very unusual and seem to be machine-generated.

Essentially, a bit of the text is removed, and random technical gibberish is inserted in random places in the text. The gibberish may be derived from the question's tags.

Now, I would normally assume that this was a bot that strikes from different IP addresses each time, but with a specific piece of information, that doesn't seem very likely.

Every time I get one of these edits, it turns out to be an audit, and I need to reject it as vandalism to succeed.

Also, the icon of the user that made the edit is a randomly selected user without many achievements, but once I reject the edit, the user icon turns into that of the Community user.

This information makes me think that this is a part of Stack Overflow, to generated edits to use as audits when there aren't very many bad edits around.

Is this correct? And if so, are you going to delete this as a spoiler?

Comment: I was actually fooled by the audits in an (I think) unintended way at first - thought they were some strange bug in the review system, since the inserted text was *total* nonsense, yet not of a kind that would normally be inserted by a spam bot. So, I always *skipped* them, since I had no idea if this "bug" hid an actually good edit (or bad for that matter). So, only started rejecting them after a hearing of audits, although I never approved one...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Congratulations, you're paying good attention to [suggested edit audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165489/155160). Keep up the good work. :)

The fact that these exist is public knowledge. They're designed to be bad edits, but not so bad that people who just casually glance at them may be fooled. And some are, so these are certainly doing their job.

Comment: This is a much less exciting answer than, "Yes, SE has become self aware, and is attempting to reach out to sympathetic humans by inserting stream of consciousness poetry into suggested edits." Just saying.

Comment: @jball We are sorry to disappoint. Those responsible will be sacked...err...wait.

Comment: This reminds me of heating a refrigerator's walls to keep it self defrosting.  No frost, but uses the oxymoronic heat-to-cool engine <-- and that was no Boy Coder auto-generated mumbo jumbo...