# Please don't use comments containing vulgarities for suggested edit review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, edit-summary

I come across this comment while reviewing [a suggested edit audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3446530):

[image: a very rude comment]

I don't think system-generated messages should contain such language. Can they be chosen more carefully, please?

Comment: What did it say when you passed the audit?

Comment: It sometimes gets frustrated, as it can't leave its cage.

Comment: another reason to hate the edit audit reviews I suppose. Still think we are not doing these right

Comment: It's Won't's fault: [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170683/162704)

Comment: @Kate I think the edit audits are the best of the audits. I've never seen one that could be disputed. The other queue audits though...

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember the user who attempted the edit this was based on. That guy was fun. I suppose when you seed these based on actual edits, you're eventually going to pull one from a troll. Maybe a little keyword filtering could keep titles like this out.

Comment: @jball that's not my measure of a good audit. A good audit identifies bad reviewers without upsetting good ones or causing them to stop reviewing. I understand some people would fail an edit review that consisted of adding the word AUDIT 5 times in the body of the post with a summary comment that said "click REJECT if you're actually reading this because this is an audit" but I would prefer that to the gibberish and occasional swearing that happens now. What I really want is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection

Comment: @BradLarson The audit edits are [not based on actual edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165489/162704). Not sure about the edit description though.

Comment: @Yannis - Sorry, meant the descriptions. Those are based on ones from actual edits.

Comment: @Kate, just to clarify, I'm not saying they are good, just that they're the least bad of the bunch. I think minimizing false positivies while still catching robo reviewers is more important than many other people do here, so I get that when I say best, it's not a universal thing. Anyhow, the suggested edits is the best in terms of false positives. The offensive potential should be mitigated though. Aside, I fully support your idea of bringing in a human factor to review selections.