# Why is offensive content added to review "trick" questions?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, review-audits, offensive

### Why I even ask

I'm over in Super User review and see an item pop up in **suggested edits** that appeared to be vandalism with *hate crime type speech* in it of prejudice based on skin color with the word "*die*" really.

It turns out it's a trick/test question so I look at the [main post](https://superuser.com/questions/1246970/windows-explorer-hang-after-startup), and it has no history of it ever being vandalized in the past either, but this language still populates here with such words.

---

### What I saw

Typically I'd quote the referenced material, but I'd prefer not for what this question is about specifically (the speech/words used) and who is responsible for that.

Hover over the screenshot below to see the offensive content:

> [image]

---

### Question

I guess my question would be to let the community know who specifically is responsible for content or otherwise the design of such an algorithm to use language of this nature in a test review audit?

This has ***never been edited*** (*e.g. vandalism history*) so this could imply someone arbitrarily put this language in this test question/review audit item or into the algorithm of words to use, etc.?

[image]

Comment: Suggested edit audits are randomly generated, probably using a [Markov chain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).  That text wasn't put in there on purpose by anyone.  Although the algorithm *could* be modified to filter that out, I'm not sure it's worth it -- I've never seen anything offensive before in a suggested edit audit, and I've seen *much* worse things in real edits.

Comment: Probably doesn't sound too reassuring tho.

Comment: FWIW, [there have been cases in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350236/3476191) where offensive posts flagged as spam were used as review audits.  There's some debate there about whether or not offensive content should be filtered from audits.

Comment: [Rejected suggested edits with the n*-word in them.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/734653/suggested-edits-with-offensive-texts)

Comment: Which indicates its presumably a useful review audit

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think so. Just because evil stuff happens doesn't mean the system should reproduce it. The reviewer who sees this is a person who might be distressed by it, just like any other site visitor. I think it's a bug that the system reproduces or propagates offensive content in any context

Comment: @Zanna please provide a complete and indisputable list of offensive content to aid the system in detecting and subsequently hiding said content.

Comment: @rene At the very least if the system already knows it's offensive (for example, words that cause flagging a comment to delete the comment instantly, content that has been deleted as rude/abusive), then the system shouldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @Zanna the whole point of audits is to include rude/abusive content based on flags. Excluding all words that were in comments or posts that were flagged will overtime exclude all English words from being used in audits. Although I'm not unsympathetic to the request made here, I fail to see how your suggestion is practical implemented, without the expense of many human resources to decide if single words are rude/offensive or not.

Comment: @rene o.O that's not what I meant, I meant, the system already knows that some words are offensive (because if a comment contains them, flagging it will cause it to auto-destruct). And that's *not* the whole point of audits I believe - the point of audits is to check the reviewer is actually paying attention - we can do that without offensive content. Nobody awake will approve a suggestion to *add* the n-word to a post, but there are less unpleasant ways to check someone is awake

Comment: @Zanna my point stands: provide a list of offensive words. The system can't do that.

Comment: Related feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209033/please-dont-use-comments-containing-vulgarities-for-suggested-edit-review-audit

Comment: Also, a near-duplicate request (though tagged as [tag:discussion]) from 2013: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201766/should-fuck-be-present-in-review-audits-intentionally-fake-suggested-edit-rev

Comment: IMO this is not a big deal. The audits are supposed to represent REAL bad edits that you could see on a site and trust me, I have seen and had said to me, a lot worse. The issue is, if some words start getting removed, then someone else will want another removed and then another. As what is offensive is highly subjective, who decides what is offensive? Offence is always taken, never given and if you are botherd by a string on a screen, computer generated at that, that is really your personal issue, not SE's.

Comment: A simple solution for those who are eaisily offended, block the words: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/foxreplace/

Comment: @rene Eh, "we can't be 100% perfect so we may as well do nothing at all" isn't a great stance either. To OP's and Zanna's points, we have a blacklist in place on a number of words we don't want appearing in the HNQ titles. I think we should look into reusing that for the suggested edit audit generator. I'll bring it up for discussion internally.

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you sir, amazing it'll be brought up for internal discussion per the simple question I asked with the detail. I would think as a company you simply do the right thing with such content and try to prevent it from being populated in the first place to pacify the concern if possible. Thanks for reading and responding accordingly.

Comment: @AdamLear I'm known for my not great stances. Thanks for looking into it but it wouldn't be high on my priority list.

Comment: @rene I think for a list, you'd simple use common sense and good judgment for words to exclude that could be offensive and it's as simple as that. Just have a list of single words to be excluded such as: f#ck, sh#t, b#tch, n##ger, wh#re, f#g, h#mo, #ss, c#ck, and so on. I'm not sure what's so hard about creating a simple list of words that probably should not be used regardless in a typing of a post here I would think. As far as priority is concerned, that should be a company decision though I would think or else take a community vote on it.

Comment: @Facebook I'm all for common sense, but I give you this: once that list is created we get people that request all kind of words they find offensive should be on that list. I'm not arguing what you find isn't offensive, I do think the solution is non-trivial and only visible for those users that already kind-of opted in to expect offensive content in the first place. I would much more like if the dev team could spend their time on the DAG priorities instead of these kind of corner cases that happens once a while. Though luck, review accordingly and call it day.

Comment: Just start with the common profane type words that just aren't appropriate to say. If its a word that would make you feel it's inappropriate for a young kid to say let alone read, then it's likely a good candidate. I'm sure they'll discuss and prioritize accordingly if they feel it's even worth the work—as a company I'd do the right thing here if it were my decision to make since the content is publicly accessible and prevent the system from creating this in the first place regardless. We'll see what comes of it when we hear back, this is FYI at a minimum I suppose otherwise.