# Exclude posts with valid "rude or abusive" flags from appearing as review audits in all review queues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-audits, inappropriate-content

Recently our member reported about inappropriate content in the question in a First Posts review audit. The question was deleted by a moderator, because it contains NSFW pictures.

Can you do something with it? For example, give moderators the ability to exclude such questions from the queue audit? Showing NSFW pictures in the queue is not a good thing.

The link to the deleted question in queue audit. <s>**Care, it contains inappropriate content! NSFW!**</s> The NSFW images have been edited out by a Stack Exchange employee, but they were there at the time this question was posted:

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/440020

Members raised flags, moderator deleted the question.

> [image]

Flags:

- Very low quality
- Spam
- Rude or abusive

As @Sonic [pointed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343436/dont-show-inappropriate-content-e-g-porn-pictures-in-the-queue-audit?noredirect=1#comment1150224_343436) in the comments, posts with helpful "rude or abusive" flags should not appear as audits, but such prohibition [only applies to the Triage and Low Quality Posts queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/2157772). Therefore, it should be implemented on First Posts and other queues as well.

Comment: Posts with helpful rude or abusive flags are excluded from appearing in reviews. The moderator should have (bindingly) flagged it as that instead of using the normal delete button.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog but this question wasn't. So, is it a bug?

Comment: It would help to have a link to the deleted post in order to be able to determine what happened. Right now, this is a feature request for a feature which already exists. Without a link to the post, it's not possible to determine if the issue was that the existing feature didn't work, or if the feature wasn't used.

Comment: @Makyen is it ok to add this link to the question?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301616/why-is-offensive-content-added-to-review-trick-questions

Comment: Yes, including a link to the post is reasonable. The only people that will be able to do anything are those that can see deleted content on the affected site. The post *might* be available in some archives. You've made it clear that the destination contains content that is NSFW. It's also important to have the link, so SE will know which image(s) to have Imgur remove from their servers.

Comment: Mind posting an English translation of the flag types?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog "Very low quality", "Spam", "Rude or abusive".
I've updated the question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If you ever need them, I collected a list of the localized flag titles in my answer to [What are the top level question & answer localized flag_option titles?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7996/what-are-the-top-level-question-answer-localized-flag-option-titles) on StackApps.

Comment: Hmm...I did some research and that exclusion [only applies to Triage and Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/2157772). It doesn't apply to First Posts. So this is a feature request to enable it for that queue and other queues too.

Comment: I’ve done what I can at the moment. I’ve edited the post, deleted the images from imgur (they may take a bit to actually delete). But even if I can’t get the change made to exclude the question from reviews, the images won’t show up.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica I'd edit the post to a Russian translation of the same, because there's a chance the same post might appear as a review audit again for someone else.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks)

Comment: @Catija we could change redaction. But the main point here is that those posts should be excluded from the queue.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Posts with validated rude/abusive flags should be excluded from being audits. Having them as audits subjects users to such things unnecessarily, unless there's evidence such things are being reviewed inaccurately. However, if you're doing reviews, then you need to be prepared for the possibility of seeing such content from live reviews. There's nothing SE can do to prevent that. After all, weeding out such content (i.e. appropriately flagging such content) is part of the purpose of having reviews, so the content is live on the site for as short a time as possible.

Comment: @Catija, the *question* now becomes: If the images are deleted and the post remains in the queue will it (or a different future instance of this problem) cause the reviewers to review incorrectly; thus failing the audit, and causing another meta post. --- Only people with diamonds (or Charcoal) should see "everything" and others should not see hate, abusiveness, p0rn, etc. Such things really have no place in an Audit since they would make the choice easy (and the Audit easy to pass); unless the post is tampered with, then an audit failure and additional discussion is more likely.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik We just changed the status from planned to deferred. This request is a bit more involved than we initially suspected, so we are rolling it into a larger Q4 project on Review Queues architecture. Appreciate your patience, and we will update this post as the work progresses.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Can this be actioned now that the review architecture is planned for the current timeline?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog This is something we will be looking into as part of our ongoing Review Queues work. Still "deferred" rather than "planned" because we are not yet at or near the active development stage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We were already excluding these posts in audits that explicitly dealt with offensive content but not in other queues that might need it.  I've copied the filtering conditions to the remaining queues.