# Suspend review privileges if community disagrees a lot

Tags: feature-request, review, review-suspension

This image should illustrate the point I'm trying to make:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SvLT.png]

---

---

I suggest that when the community generally disagrees (3 rejects vs 1 approve, 3-5 recommend deletions vs 1 looks good, etc.) too many times, the reviewer's privileges be suspended for some time.

I think a good algorithm would be this:

```
if (disagreements / total reviews >= 0.25) { suspend user from reviews }
```

Although the number may be tweaked as the community sees fit.

I think this might help (but probably not solve) the robo-reviewer problem. 416 approvals and 4 rejections is just crazy.

Comment: This Bart is far too positive as well. Ban him! Funny though, I was about to write something similar about another such user I just encountered. (2742 edit suggestions approved and 18 rejected)

Comment: @Bart Actually no, your ratio is about 1.17.

Comment: Phew. Got lucky there then. ;)

Comment: As long as it doesn't go the other way; I've been the lone dissenter **way** too much it seems.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is necessary, because the [suggested edit audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits/165489#165489) appear to be doing a great job in removing the worst rubber-stamp approvers from that queue. As others have said, I've seen cases where three of the reviewers were in the wrong (in one instance, all three are now banned from the queue).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152540/dealing-with-misguided-reviewers-of-suggested-edits-take-2 (also touched on here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152709/improving-the-quality-of-reviews-project-honeypot and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179929/are-reasonably-bad-reviewers-in-any-way-being-detected-or-punished)